# How do I upload multi/form-data with a zipped file to a rest api using pure javascript running in ie6 environment but not necessarily in the browser

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, content-type

I am trying to upload data which includes text and a zipped file to a rest api without using a form

The data is in a mixed format i.e. text and a zipped file which is contains a single xhtml file inside it

Environment: Internet explorer 6, but not in a browser

Each time i post the data, i get an http 500 status error stating that unzipping the file failed

I am assuming it could be the way I am trying to attach the zipped file to the body text

I have included the code below on what I have been trying to do. The code can not use any forms or formData object as it is not running in a browser. I tried sending some of the data to a server I have on my machine and I can receive the data, and also looks like the file comes through as binary. I am not too sure if the live server I am trying to send to expects the zip file as is as i doubt that possible to send a zip file in its raw format without trying to convert it to binary. I have a working example of it when I do it in the browser using formData object as well as in php

```
    var boundary = "xxblobxx";

    var data = "";

    /** Start a new part in our body's request (Field for theSource)*/
    data += "--" + boundary;
    data += '\r\n';
    // Describe it as form data
    data += 'content-disposition: form-data; name="theSource"';
    // There's a blank line between the metadata and the data
    data += '\r\n';
    data += '\r\n';
    // Append the text data to our body's request
    data += sRelativeSource;
    //New line
    data += '\r\n';

    /** Start a new part in our body's request (Field for theparameters)*/
    data += "--" + boundary;
    data += '\r\n';
    // Describe it as form data
    data += 'content-disposition: form-data; name="theparameters"';
    // There's a blank line between the metadata and the data
    data += '\r\n';
    data += '\r\n';
    // Append the text data to our body's request
    data += sArguments;
    //New line
    data += '\r\n';

    /**Start a new part in our body's request (Attach the file)*/
    data += "--" + boundary;
    data += '\r\n';
    //Describe it as a form data
    data += 'content-disposition: form-data; name="thefile"; filename="'+ sFileNameWithExtension+'"';
    data += '\r\n';
    // And the MIME type of the file
    data += 'Content-Type: application/zip';
    // There's a blank line between the metadata and the data
    data += '\r\n';
    data += '\r\n';
    // Append the binary data to our body's request
    data += sBinaryData;
    data += '\r\n';
    data += boundary + '--';

    var xhr = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://someurl',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "mytoken");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");  
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        try{
            if(xhr.readyState==4){
                debugger;
                if(xhr.status == 200){
                    msg = xhr.responseText;
                    debugger;                   
                }//200
                else{
                    msg = xhr.responseText;
                }                   
            }
        }catch(e)
        {
            errorMessage(e);
        }
    }
    // And finally, send our data.
    xhr.send(data);
```

When I send the file through I am expecting a binary file to be returned which is if converted is a zipped file, with a list of csv file. The fact that I am getting the error 500 unable to unzip means I can get to the sever but am not too sure if its a setting I am missing or the format in which I am sending the file

Comment: What is the format of sBinaryData?

Comment: @Pyro Its is an xhtml file that has been compressed using winzip. so it .zip file

Comment: You did not include the snippet that populates the string, so it could be anything. It might be base64 encoded which normally isn't necessary.

Zip uses Content-Type: application/zip - you can try application/octet-stream as well.

You might need to add a -- before the closing boundry as well as after, you only seem to it after

Something you can try, is to explicitly specify the encoding as UTF-8.
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary="+boundary);

A more complex boundry might also help - but that seems unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: @Pyro I want to be able to pick up the file from my local machine without use of a form but at the end of the day when I assign it to sBinaryData, it should be the same format as having browsed for it from a form in html and submitting. I hope that answers the question on format of sBinaryData